# Nexted subscribes in rxjs

Tags: angular, performance, rxjs, google-cloud-storage, ionic4

I have this function which gets information from every requests and passes it to the next one. What is the best way to implement this. This works but I'm afraid this can have some issues in the long term given that I have nested subscriptions.

```
onSubmit(){


    this.loadingController.create({keyboardClose:true, message:'Submitting Info...'})
    .then(loadingEl => {
      loadingEl.present()

      this.sharedService.uploadImage(this.state['image']).subscribe(imgUrl => {
 
        this.sharedService.addVisitor(this.state['first_name'], 
                                      this.state['last_name'], 
                                      this.state['role'], 
                                      this.location,
                                      imgUrl,
                                      this.state['visitee_email'],
                                      this.state['visitee_phone'],
                                      this.state['visitee_name'],
                                      this.state['company'])
        .subscribe(visitor => {

          console.log(visitor)

          this.sharedService.addQuestionnaire(visitor.id)
          .subscribe(questionnaire => {
    
            console.log(questionnaire)
            
            //dismiss the loading element
            loadingEl.dismiss();  
    
            // navigate away
            this.router.navigate(['/home'])
        
          })
        
        })

      }, error => {
        loadingEl.dismiss()
        console.log(error)
        this.alertController.create({header: "An error ocurred...", 
                                    message: "Could not submit visitor info.", 
                                    buttons: [{text: 'Okay', handler: () => this.router.navigateByUrl('/home')}]}).then(alertEl => {
                                      alertEl.present()
                                    })
      })

    })
    
  }

}
```

1. I upload image, to get the url from cloud storage
2. Make another request to add a visitor and get the visitor id
3. afterward I upload an existing inputted questionnaire to another api

if someone can shrink or help me make this piece of code better will be much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have it like this instead:

```
import { switchMap, catchError, throwError } from 'rxjs/operators';


this.sharedService
  .uploadImage(this.state['image'])
  .pipe(
    switchMap(imgUrl => this.sharedService              
      .addVisitor(
        this.state['first_name'], 
        this.state['last_name'], 
        this.state['role'], 
        this.location,
        imgUrl,
        this.state['visitee_email'],
        this.state['visitee_phone'],
        this.state['visitee_name'],
        this.state['company']
      )
    ),
    switchMap(({ id }) => this.sharedService.addQuestionnaire(id)),
    catchError((error: any) => throwError(error))
  )
  .subscribe(
    questionnaire => {
      console.log(questionnaire)
            
      loadingEl.dismiss();  
    
      this.router.navigate(['/home'])   
    },
    error => {
      loadingEl.dismiss()

      console.log(error)
      
      this.alertController.create({
        header: "An error ocurred...", 
        message: "Could not submit visitor info.", 
        buttons: [{text: 'Okay', 
        handler: () => this.router.navigateByUrl('/home')}]}).then(alertEl => alertEl.present())
    }
  );
```